# Vulkan: Errors when adding 3rd descriptor

Tags: c++, dynamic, vulkan, descriptor, uniform

I have a Vulkan program that has descriptors for a Uniform buffer and a Combined image sampler. I tried to add a 3rd descriptor to for a Dynamic Uniform buffer but i have got validation layer errors.

Code with 3 descriptors (not working):

```
void createDescriptorSetLayoutR() {

        VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding uboLayoutBinding{};
        uboLayoutBinding.binding = 0;
        uboLayoutBinding.descriptorCount = 1;
        uboLayoutBinding.descriptorType = VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_UNIFORM_BUFFER;
        uboLayoutBinding.pImmutableSamplers = nullptr;
        uboLayoutBinding.stageFlags = VK_SHADER_STAGE_VERTEX_BIT;

        VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding samplerLayoutBinding{};
        samplerLayoutBinding.binding = 1;
        samplerLayoutBinding.descriptorCount = 1;
        samplerLayoutBinding.descriptorType = VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_COMBINED_IMAGE_SAMPLER;
        samplerLayoutBinding.pImmutableSamplers = nullptr;
        samplerLayoutBinding.stageFlags = VK_SHADER_STAGE_FRAGMENT_BIT;

        VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding DuboLayoutBinding{};
        uboLayoutBinding.binding = 2;
        uboLayoutBinding.descriptorCount = 1;
        uboLayoutBinding.descriptorType = VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_UNIFORM_BUFFER_DYNAMIC;
        uboLayoutBinding.pImmutableSamplers = nullptr;
        uboLayoutBinding.stageFlags = VK_SHADER_STAGE_VERTEX_BIT;

        std::array<VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding, 3> bindings = {uboLayoutBinding, samplerLayoutBinding, DuboLayoutBinding};
        VkDescriptorSetLayoutCreateInfo layoutInfo{};
        layoutInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DESCRIPTOR_SET_LAYOUT_CREATE_INFO;
        layoutInfo.bindingCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(bindings.size());
        layoutInfo.pBindings = bindings.data();

        if (vkCreateDescriptorSetLayout(device, &layoutInfo, nullptr, &descriptorSetLayout) != VK_SUCCESS) {
            throw std::runtime_error("failed to create descriptor set layout!");
        }
    }
```

```
void createDescriptorPoolR() {

        std::array<VkDescriptorPoolSize, 3> poolSizes{};
        poolSizes[0].type = VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_UNIFORM_BUFFER;
        poolSizes[0].descriptorCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(MAX_FRAMES_IN_FLIGHT);

        poolSizes[1].type = VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_COMBINED_IMAGE_SAMPLER;
        poolSizes[1].descriptorCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(MAX_FRAMES_IN_FLIGHT);

        poolSizes[2].type = VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_UNIFORM_BUFFER_DYNAMIC;
        poolSizes[2].descriptorCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(MAX_FRAMES_IN_FLIGHT);

        VkDescriptorPoolCreateInfo poolInfo{};
        poolInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DESCRIPTOR_POOL_CREATE_INFO;
        poolInfo.poolSizeCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(poolSizes.size());
        poolInfo.pPoolSizes = poolSizes.data();
        poolInfo.maxSets = static_cast<uint32_t>(MAX_FRAMES_IN_FLIGHT);

        if (vkCreateDescriptorPool(device, &poolInfo, nullptr, &descriptorPool) != VK_SUCCESS) {
            throw std::runtime_error("failed to create descriptor pool!");
        }
    }
```

```
void createDescriptorSetsR() {

        std::vector<VkDescriptorSetLayout> layouts(MAX_FRAMES_IN_FLIGHT, descriptorSetLayout);
        VkDescriptorSetAllocateInfo allocInfo{};
        allocInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DESCRIPTOR_SET_ALLOCATE_INFO;
        allocInfo.descriptorPool = descriptorPool;
        allocInfo.descriptorSetCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(MAX_FRAMES_IN_FLIGHT);
        allocInfo.pSetLayouts = layouts.data();

        descriptorSets.resize(MAX_FRAMES_IN_FLIGHT);
        if (vkAllocateDescriptorSets(device, &allocInfo, descriptorSets.data()) != VK_SUCCESS) {

            throw std::runtime_error("failed to allocate descriptor sets!");

        }

        for (size_t i = 0; i < MAX_FRAMES_IN_FLIGHT; i++) {

            VkDescriptorBufferInfo bufferInfo{};
            bufferInfo.buffer = uniformBuffers[i];
            bufferInfo.offset = 0;
            bufferInfo.range = sizeof(UniformBufferObject);

            VkDescriptorImageInfo imageInfo{};
            imageInfo.imageLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL;
            imageInfo.imageView = textureImageView;
            imageInfo.sampler = textureSampler;

            VkDescriptorBufferInfo bufferInfo_D{};
            bufferInfo_D.buffer = Dubos[i];
            bufferInfo_D.offset = 0;
            bufferInfo_D.range = sizeof(Dubo);

            std::array<VkWriteDescriptorSet, 3> descriptorWrites{};

            descriptorWrites[0].sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_WRITE_DESCRIPTOR_SET;
            descriptorWrites[0].dstSet = descriptorSets[i];
            descriptorWrites[0].dstBinding = 0;
            descriptorWrites[0].dstArrayElement = 0;
            descriptorWrites[0].descriptorType = VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_UNIFORM_BUFFER;
            descriptorWrites[0].descriptorCount = 1;
            descriptorWrites[0].pBufferInfo = &bufferInfo;

            descriptorWrites[1].sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_WRITE_DESCRIPTOR_SET;
            descriptorWrites[1].dstSet = descriptorSets[i];
            descriptorWrites[1].dstBinding = 1;
            descriptorWrites[1].dstArrayElement = 0;
            descriptorWrites[1].descriptorType = VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_COMBINED_IMAGE_SAMPLER;
            descriptorWrites[1].descriptorCount = 1;
            descriptorWrites[1].pImageInfo = &imageInfo;

            descriptorWrites[2].sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_WRITE_DESCRIPTOR_SET;
            descriptorWrites[2].dstSet = descriptorSets[i];
            descriptorWrites[2].dstBinding = 2;
            descriptorWrites[2].dstArrayElement = 0;
            descriptorWrites[2].descriptorType = VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_UNIFORM_BUFFER_DYNAMIC;
            descriptorWrites[2].descriptorCount = 1;
            descriptorWrites[2].pBufferInfo = &bufferInfo_D;

            vkUpdateDescriptorSets(device, static_cast<uint32_t>(descriptorWrites.size()), descriptorWrites.data(), 0, nullptr);
        }
    }
```

---

Render Pass code:

```
vkCmdBeginRenderPass(commandBuffer, &renderPassInfo, VK_SUBPASS_CONTENTS_INLINE);

    vkCmdBindPipeline(commandBuffer, VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS, graphicsPipeline);

    VkBuffer vertexBuffers[] = {vertexBuffer};
    VkDeviceSize offsets[] = {0};
    uint32_t dynamicOffset  = 0;

    vkCmdBindDescriptorSets(commandBuffer, VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS, pipelineLayout, 0, 1, &descriptorSets[currentFrame], 1, &dynamicOffset);

    vkCmdDrawIndexed(commandBuffer, static_cast<uint32_t>(indices.size()), 1, 0, 0, 0);

vkCmdEndRenderPass(commandBuffer);
```

---

Errors:

```
validation layer: Validation Error: [ VUID-VkGraphicsPipelineCreateInfo-layout-00756 ] Object 0: handle = 0x55cc4904a330, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_DEVICE; | MessageID = 0x45717876 | Shader uses descriptor slot 0.0 but descriptor not accessible from stage VK_SHADER_STAGE_VERTEX_BIT The Vulkan spec states: layout must be consistent with all shaders specified in pStages (https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/html/vkspec.html#VUID-VkGraphicsPipelineCreateInfo-layout-00756)

validation layer: Validation Error: [ VUID-VkWriteDescriptorSet-dstBinding-00316 ] Object 0: handle = 0x980b0000000002e, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_DESCRIPTOR_SET; | MessageID = 0xcd9212c1 | vkUpdateDescriptorSets() pDescriptorWrites[0] failed write update validation for VkDescriptorSet 0x980b0000000002e[] with error: VkDescriptorSet 0x980b0000000002e[] allocated with VkDescriptorSetLayout 0xec4bec000000000b[] cannot updated binding 0 that has 0 descriptors. The Vulkan spec states: dstBinding must be a binding with a non-zero descriptorCount (https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/html/vkspec.html#VUID-VkWriteDescriptorSet-dstBinding-00316)

validation layer: Validation Error: [ VUID-VkWriteDescriptorSet-dstBinding-00316 ] Object 0: handle = 0x4b7df1000000002f, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_DESCRIPTOR_SET; | MessageID = 0xcd9212c1 | vkUpdateDescriptorSets() pDescriptorWrites[0] failed write update validation for VkDescriptorSet 0x4b7df1000000002f[] with error: VkDescriptorSet 0x4b7df1000000002f[] allocated with VkDescriptorSetLayout 0xec4bec000000000b[] cannot updated binding 0 that has 0 descriptors. The Vulkan spec states: dstBinding must be a binding with a non-zero descriptorCount (https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/html/vkspec.html#VUID-VkWriteDescriptorSet-dstBinding-00316)

validation layer: Validation Error: [ VUID-vkResetFences-pFences-01123 ] Object 0: handle = 0x4fac1c0000000032, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_FENCE; | MessageID = 0x68a5074e | VkFence 0x4fac1c0000000032[] is in use. The Vulkan spec states: Each element of pFences must not be currently associated with any queue command that has not yet completed execution on that queue (https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/html/vkspec.html#VUID-vkResetFences-pFences-01123)

validation layer: Validation Error: [ VUID-vkResetCommandBuffer-commandBuffer-00045 ] Object 0: handle = 0x55cc494b8160, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_COMMAND_BUFFER; | MessageID = 0x1e7883ea | Attempt to reset VkCommandBuffer 0x55cc494b8160[] which is in use. The Vulkan spec states: commandBuffer must not be in the pending state (https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/html/vkspec.html#VUID-vkResetCommandBuffer-commandBuffer-00045)

failed to submit draw command buffer!
```

---

---

I have managed to change the code such that there are 2 descriptors with one being for the Combined image sampler and the other being for a Dynamic Uniform buffer.

Would it be better to just store the data, that i want to store in the regular Uniform buffer, at the start of the Dynamic Uniform buffer and just offset past it when accessing my dynamic data (Model matrices).

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2):

There is a typo in your code:

```
VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding DuboLayoutBinding{};
uboLayoutBinding.binding = 2;
// ...
```

So you create an empty **Dubo**LayoutBinding and overwriting **ubo**LayoutBinding.